# How to stop a "black box" operation?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I am using an asynchronous delegate that invokes a method which loads an xml file into an XPathDocument. If  the xml is too big to fit into memory it never finishes loading.  the code below works if the xml file is successfully loaded into the XPathDocument.  I have been able to use a timer event that executes the  asyncXpath.EndInvoke(result) statement and that works to end the CreateDocument method, but it does not stop the XPathDocument from loading. My conclusion is that the only thing I can do is to issue an Application.End statement to kill the application. Does anyone know how to stop a blackbox operation such as loading an XPathDocument.

```
delegate bool AsyncXpathQueryCaller(string xmlfile 

bool found = false; 
AsyncXpathQueryCaller asyncXpath = new 
AsyncXpathQueryCaller(CreateDocument); 
IAsyncResult result = asyncXpath.BeginInvoke(xmlfile, null, null); 
while (!result.IsCompleted) 
{ 
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(100, false); 

} 
found = asyncXpath.EndInvoke(result);


private bool CreateDocument (string xmlfile)
{
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(xmlfile);
}
```

Comment: If the document is that large, I would suggest using a forward-only reader to read/process the data. This will be faster and also can be interrupted as you read through the file if necessary.

Comment: @Tim - There's only so many ways to create an XPathDocument object, all of which involve letting the constructor control the file loading.

Comment: @KeithS - I was thinking more of an XmlReader...if the document in question is THAT big, it could be read in chunks, transformed/parsed/etc if needed one chunk at a time. Not sure if it fits in this case, that's why I posted a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I need to do xpath queries after xml is loaded and I need the backward looking axes, like ancestor::, so XPathDocument or XmlDocument are my only options(within .net).

Comment: So, are you asking how to kill a thread?  Cause I think I've heard you can't reliably do it without killing the whole process...

Comment: @Bill Seacham: It's very common to use a SAX approach when dealing with these issues. You really should reconsider the tools you have choosen.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) before you try to load it and checking the size?  If it's too big just skip it.

Something like this:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(xmlfile);
if(fi.Length < /*some huge number*/)
{
  //load the file
}
```

Comment: If you could define "too big" I would upvote your answer. Since I doubt you can, I'm tempted to downvote.

Comment: It just occurred to me that this is only going to reduce the likelihood of the problem. At some point the algorithm is going to guess wrong and attempt to load a file that won't work. So this doesn't solve the OP's problem, it just gives him two more (figuring out what *some huge number* is, and them rejecting files that are larger than that number but would still work).

Comment: No, my solution is fine.  You're just upset that I said yours was a poor solution (which it is).  I stand by what I said, but if this makes you feel better more power to you.

Comment: If you could articulate precisely what magic happens in your *some huge number* comment, I would agree that your answer is fine. Furthermore, if you could articulare exactly why terminating a thread that's running the `XPathDocument` constructor was a bad idea, I would agree with you that my answer is poor. Feel free to do either or both (good luck solving the halting problem, though)!

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a FileStream and give it to the constructor, but before you do, look at its Length property, and if it's too long, just return an error.

Comment: with xml there is no way to know how long is too long. it depends on the structure and content of the xml more than the file length. I have no advance knowledge of any characteristics of the xml -could be anything.

Comment: I disagree; file length is proportional to file contents. There are only two things I can think of that would cause a relatively small-size file to blow up in your face: tags nested too deeply for the parser (unlikely), and "billion laughs"-type exploits where recursive entity definitions parse out to a bajillion-character value.

Comment: the file may  be too large for available memory. Is there a way to kill the thread that .net creates when the XPathDocument is created?

Comment: @Bill, are you smarter than me, or not making sense?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I just realized that [KeithS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964534/how-to-stop-a-black-box-operation/4964595#4964595) has come close to a good answer. The basic idea is that you call the [XPathDocument constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tcc71ye.aspx) that accepts a `Stream` which wraps a `FileStream`. The object you pass it should implement the `Read(byte[], int, int)` function to call the wrapped `FileStream`'s `Read` function, or throw an exception if the operation has timed out. Here's a code sample:

```
class XmlStream : FileStream
{
    DateTime deadline;

    public XmlStream(string filename, TimeSpan timeout)
           : base(filename, FileMode.Open)
    {
        deadline = DateTime.UtcNow + timeout;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] array, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (DateTime.UtcNow > deadline)
            throw new TimeoutException();
        return base.Read(array, offset, count);
    }
}
```

Here's some code that reads in `document`, but times out after 1 second:

```
    bool found = true;
    using(var stream = new XmlStream(document, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
    try
    {
        xpath = new XPathDocument(stream);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        found = false;
    }
```

If you create a separate thread instead of doing a `BeginInvoke`, you can just abort the thread when a timer ticks (or somebody clicks "Cancel"). While aborting threads is generally not advisable because it could be holding a lock or have global data in an inconsistent state, in this case it should be fine because your thread would not be holding a lock or accessing global data.

Here's the code for this method that does the same as the previous sample:

```
    bool found = false;
    thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        xpath = new XPathDocument(document);
        found = true;
    });
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    thread.Abort();
```

If you're uncomfortable with aborting threads in your own app domain, you can create the document in another app domain and call `AppDomain.Unload` on it if it takes too long. That will require some marshalling, but probably won't have too much overhead.

The ultimate way to be able to kill a process is to run it in a separate process and use some sort of remoting interface to access it. That's probably even messier that the other options, though, as you have to worry about finding the executable, passing parameters, some user terminating it, and so on.

Comment: You're correct in saying it's not good to abort threads.  I would disagree that this is the best option...

Comment: @Abe Miessler: I agree with you, but do note that this answers the OP questions, others are giving advices.

Comment: I tried your timer suggestion to abort the thread. It stops the invoked method, but the "black box" process of loading the xpathdocument continues. Task manager shows only 3Mb memory left(started with about 800Mb). xml file size is 266Mb. Maybe the xmpathdocument is loaded in a separate thread handled by .net, not my application. I even tried application.exit and it still does not stop it.

Comment: @Bill: Did you use a separate thread to run `BeginInvoke`, or did you just call `new XPathDocument` on the separate thread? If the CPU usage stops, you're doing it right. The memory will be consumed until the garbage collection runs (call `GC.Collect()` to do it manually.

Comment: @Bill Seacham: I've edited my answer to have working sample code for two different methods.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed by Abe Miessler it is sensible to check the file size even before attempting to load it into an XPathDocument.

**How would one decide what should be the limit**?

There is no exact rule, but I have heard people say that you should multiply the file size by 5 and then the result is close to the memory that the XmlDocument will require in order for the text to be loaded/parsed.

Comment: OK, so let's say that you can determine how much memory the `XmlDocument` will use. How do you know if that's "too much"?

Comment: @Gabe: Most operating systems provide info about the current free memory available -- via particular functions/APIs

Comment: What does "current free memory" mean? Is it available physical memory? Virtual memory? What good is it anyway? By the time you're done processing the XML, more memory could have been released or allocated.

Comment: @Gabe: This may be a trial and error process as the 5 to 1 rule is not absolute, but once the right factor is determined, then one will be able to control the process almost completely. As for the dynamics of memory allocation, yes, you are right, however it would be unwise to run anything else at the same time if it is questionable that all available memory will suffice for parsing/processing the XML document.

Comment: I parsed a 20MB XML file and found that it took about 60MB of memory. Then I added some whitespace, made the tag names longer, and saved it as UTF-16. Even though semantically it was the same file, it grew to 90MB, yet it *still* consumed only about 60MB of memory when parsed. In other words, the 5:1 rule is meaningless.

Comment: @Gabe:  The rule is *not* meaningless. It means that you can establish the typical ratio for *your* XML files, then use that data to prevent long and useless processeing.